# C# - How to convert strange hex-like value to string

Tags: c#

I have this value that appears to be hex, but I can't do a hex-to-string conversion on it:

**http:0x8efabf24**

If you slap that in your address bar, it goes to Google. I tried converting to hex, and got "Could not find any recognizable digits" as the error, even when stripping off the "http:" at the beginning.

I want to convert it to a string, so I can figure out if it's a url, but I haven't a clue how to convert it.

Comment: I expect it's an IP address.

Comment: If you put the 8efabf24 part into [this page](https://www.browserling.com/tools/hex-to-ip) it comes out with 142.250.191.36, which goes to Google.

Comment: It is *already* a string.  How can it be otherwise if it contains 'http`; those are not hex values

Comment: 1. Yeah, I know it's an IP address.
2. I know it goes to google - I said as much in my question.
3. I know it's a "string" - I am asking for the "translation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the IP address from that like this:

```cs
string input = "http:0x8efabf24";
if (input.StartsWith("http:0x"))
{
    input = input.Substring(7);
}

long ipValue = Convert.ToInt64(input, 16);

if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    // Reverse the order of the bytes
    ipValue = (ipValue & 0xFF) << 24
        | ((ipValue >> 8) & 0xFF) << 16
        | ((ipValue >> 16) & 0xFF) << 8
        | (ipValue >> 24);
}

IPAddress ip = new IPAddress(ipValue);
Console.WriteLine(ip.ToString());
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was looking for. A "translation" from the original string into something readable. Thank you.